# Can I use Gradle to build, referencing source JARs of other projects?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am building a Java project, call it A.  A has sources in `A/src/main/java`.  There are other projects B, C, D (more, actually), and they have `B/src/main/java`, `C/src/main/java` , `D/src/main/java`.  When I took over this project A, I noticed that the old JBuilder build script for A referenced the sources of B, C and D in parallel directories.  I don't like that, because source files in those other directories could change.  I want to modify the build, using Gradle, so that versioned sources of the other projects are pulled from a local Maven repo, and, from A's perspective, during compilation I reference the source `.zip` files of the other projects.  Can I do that with Gradle?

Comment: Build B, C and D and publish the built artifacts in your Maven repo. Then use them as dependencies, just as you would do with any other Maven dependency. You don't need their sources (other then for debugging). You need their compiled class files.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.